# dominoes combinatory problem

Tags: combinatorics

Thera are 28 dominoes, and each one has two numbers of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 (and can be repeated).A hand contains 7 dominoes. A double is a tile tha has the same numbers(e.g 6-6) 
How many different hands are there that contain 2 doubles?
How many different hands are there that contain 4 tiles with the same number?
How many different ways hands are there that contain 2 doubles and 4 tiles with the same number? I dont´ have any clue how to do them.... I really appreciate your help

Comment: It is common courtesy to post some of your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

The others will be similar.

There are $\binom{7}{2}$ ways to pick two doubles from the 7. Then there are $\binom{21}{5}$ ways to pick the remaining dominoes so there are no doubles. So the number of hands with exactly two doubles in $\binom{7}{2}\binom{21}{5}$.

Comment: The answer may be more complicated. Suppose for example that we have four $6$'s, as in say $36$, $46$, $56$, $66$. Now consider the domino $46$. If we also have $14$, $24$, and $34$, that gives us also four $4$'s. If this hand is counted as a hand that has $4$ tiles with the same number, then your formula double counts this.

Comment: thank you very much!!! but my teacher said that we need to substract $\sum_{i=1}^6 i{7\choose 4}{6\choose 3}$ in the second problem beacuse he said that some dominoes are repeated but I don´t know why he did this

Comment: The comment that @AndréNicolas made is correct that term may be the double counting but I don't see it right away.

Comment: so I need to substract $\sum_{i=1}^6 i{7\choose 4}{6\choose3}$ ?

Comment: This answer of the first question is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

1)If you mean the number of hands containing *exactly* two doubles,

there are 7 + C(2,7) possibilities for the two doubles(the doubles can be alike or different). For each of the remaining 5 dominoes, they can have any two numbers provided they are different. There are C(5,C(2,7)) ways of forming the remaining 5 dominoes for a given pair of doubles.
So in total, you have [7 + C(2,7)].C(5,C(2,7)) different hands that contain exactly 2 doubles.

2)There are 7 + C(2,7) possibilities for the 4 similar dominoes. The remaining 3 can have any pair of numbers except that of the other 4. There are C(3,C(2,7)) - 1 possibilities for these 3 dominoes, for a given 4 alike dominoes.

So, there are [7 + C(2,7)]. [C(3,C(2,7)) - 1] hands with exactly 4 similar tiles.

3)
Assuming you want exactly 2 doubles and exactly 4 similar tiles, 
there are 7 + C(2,7) possibilities for the two doubles. The 4 alike tiles cannot include the doubles (since there must be exactly 2 doubles). For the 4 tiles of the same number, there are C(2,7) possibilities. The remaining tile can be anything except a double or the same as the 4 alike tiles. This makes C(2,7) - 1 ways for the remaining tile.

So  there are [7 + C(2,7)].C(2,7).[C(2,7) - 1] different hands with exactly 2 doubles and exactly 4 similar tiles.